# Datatables won't render with CDN installation

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables

I am trying to implement the most basic installation of datatable, where I failed to initialize it. Here is my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title> Dashboard </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>
    <table id="table_id" class="display">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column A</th>
                <th>Column B</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
                <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    
  </body>
</html>
```

I have added link to CSS and JS file via CDN, and also referred to my `main.js` file which is:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#table_id').DataTable();
} );
```

However, when I opened this HTML file, the table is still in plain status and not rendered as the examples in [this official document](https://datatables.net/manual/installation). Where did I do wrong?

Comment: You should have seen an error in the browser console for this. Did you check that? Use F12 to open your browser tools, if you are not familiar with it.